# How to validate a response in karate when you don't know the structure?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to write some karate tests that check a response for some expected structure. For example, there is an object that looks like this:

```
{
  'true|true':'disabled',
  'true|false':'locked',
  'false|false':'enabled',
  'false|true':'disabled',
  'default':'enabled'
}
```

However, the keys and values could be any strings. There must be a way to specify this, but I'm at a loss for how to do this in a generic way.

Essentially, what I would like to test is that 1) the object is not empty, 2) each of the keys and values is a string (not an object and not null).

The basic match looks like this:

```
* def objects = $fields..objects
  And match each objects ==
  """
  {
      key1: '#? isString(_)',
      key2: '#? isString(_)'
    }
    """
```

It looks like the names of the keys must be known in advance, so perhaps match expressions are not the appropriate way to test this.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract all keys like this:

```
* def keys = karate.keysOf(object)
```

So once you have that, you are in business:

```
* def foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }
* def keys = karate.keysOf(foo)
* match each keys == '#string'
* assert keys.length > 0
```

See JSON tranforms for other ideas, e.g. `karate.forEach()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms